# Is 'exit' a universally supported way of stopping execution in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, exit

I'm new to JavaScript, and found by accident that the following code works as I want:

```
alert("This shows");
exit;
alert("This doesn't show");
```

I want to early terminate all subsequent JavaScript on the current page. This works in the browsers I've tested it in. But I can't find any documentation that this is a legitimate keyword in JavaScript, and as such I'm worried that some browsers might not support it. All other suggestions mention 'return', but I'm not returning from a function, simply stopping the proceeding sequential JavaScript execution.

Is there any specific documentation for exit;?

Comment: not sure where you learned `exit`... It works because it throws an error.... It will not work when something is defined as exit or there is an id of exit on the page. If you are trying to just stop the execution, than throw an error

Comment: use `return` statement

Comment: It's basically a worse form of `throw new Error()`.

Comment: @HamzaRashid Note *"I want to early terminate all subsequent javascript on the current page."*.   `return` would only terminate the current scope, whereas throwing an error will terminate all execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "exit" in JavaScript. All you did was introduce an error on the page.

Looking at the console you would see `Uncaught ReferenceError: exit is not defined`

When would it not work?

- If you named a variable exit (and is in scope).
- If the browser converts ids into global variables and an id happened to be exit.

What should you do?

- Use [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

Answer (score 0):

I'd stay far away from that, your local testing in the browser notwithstanding. (You may be conceptually borrowing from NodeJS's process.exit()...)

Generally speaking use a Google search like this "mdn js exit" to get to the heart of the matter.  MDN is the Mozilla Developer Network, a credible source for all things web, especially syntax. I add "js" as a hint to Google that I'm looking for JavaScript information and then of course the term you are actually interested in.

I find no info on the use of 'exit'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use  `return` statement for that situation, also return can also fetch some value.

Please be guided: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: If possible, always favor Mozilla Developer Network over other sources. (I am not affiliated with them.) They are open-source while many others are not.

Comment: Note that OP said *"I want to early terminate all subsequent javascript on the current page."* `return` would only stop execution of the current block, whereas throwing an error will stop all subsequent execution. ([Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/w0sfq3jg/))

Comment: given the case of jonsploder, he just want to prevent the second alert(), that's why I suggested return but KUDOS to you sir

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has only a `break` keyword. There is no `exit` keyword defined in ECMAScript documentation.